# Semantic UI force install

Tags: javascript, gulp

1. I installed semantic ui in my project. (`bower install semantic-ui`)
2. I installed semantic ui dependencies. (`cd semantic/` , `gulp install`)
3. Next I want to build a gulp task which installs semantic ui
   automatically, therefor I create a shell task (`cd semantic/ && gulp install`)

Now when I execute this gulp task, semantic always asks me some questions during the installation phase. Is there any way to get rid of those and just force installation of semantic? (`gulp install --force` doesn't help)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing separate gulp file. Write your task inside gulpfile.js which came along with semantic ui like this

```
gulp.task('default', false, [
  'watch','your_own_task name'
]);
```

that task should have your files that need to bundle

Answer (score 0):

In theory you need a `semantic.json` file which contains your configuraton. But this doesn't work well. The problem is discussed here: https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/1816

If you don't need to make customizations to Semantic UI you could use a prebuild package. I don't know about bower but in npm you can use [semantic-ui-css](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-CSS):

```
npm install semantic-ui-css
```